# How to work with canvas and text in javafx

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am new to JavaFX and I am trying to display a rational number.
For example for the number 5/7 I want the program to show the following:

[image: 5/7]

Here is the code I've tried to use in order to get the result (but it shows nothing but a blank white pane):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    Font fontLarge = Font.font("Droid Sans", FontWeight.BOLD, 15);
    Font fontSmall = Font.font("Droid Sans", FontWeight.BOLD, 10);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Group root = new Group();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);

        root.getChildren().add(getBoxOfRationalNumber("5", "7"));
        scene.setRoot(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public VBox getBoxOfRationalNumber(String theNum, String theDenom) {
        VBox vb = new VBox();

        final Canvas num = new Canvas();
        final Canvas denom = new Canvas();
        final Canvas line = new Canvas();

        GraphicsContext gNum = num.getGraphicsContext2D();
        GraphicsContext gDenom = denom.getGraphicsContext2D();
        GraphicsContext gLine = line.getGraphicsContext2D();

        gLine.setFont(fontLarge);
        gNum.setFont(fontLarge);
        gDenom.setFont(fontLarge);

        gLine.fillText("______", 0, 0);
        gNum.fillText(theNum, 0, 0);
        gDenom.fillText(theDenom, 0, 0);

        vb.getChildren().add(num);
        vb.getChildren().add(line);
        vb.getChildren().add(denom);
        return vb;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include your code, instead of providing a link to it. What happens, and how is it different from the expected outcome?

Comment: Hi James, sorry I am new to stackoverflow and it would not let me add an image.. anyway, i added the missing information (i get blank white window instead of the image i attached)

p.s.
Thanks a lot for Veluria that help me edit the post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although, you could use a canvas for this, I advise to not try to solve this problem with a canvas.  In your case, using only scene graph nodes rather than canvas is most likely a more appropriate solution to your problem.

Here is a sample solution using scene graph nodes.

[image: fractions]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FractionDisplay extends Application {
    private class Fraction extends VBox {
        private double offset;

        public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator) {
            init(numerator + "", denominator + "");
        }

        public Fraction(String numerator, String denominator) {
            init(numerator, denominator);
        }

        private void init(String numerator, String denominator) {
            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

            Text numeratorText   = new Text(numerator);
            Text denominatorText = new Text(denominator);

            offset = numeratorText.getBaselineOffset() * 1.5;

            double dividerWidth =
                    Math.max(
                            numeratorText.getLayoutBounds().getWidth(),
                            denominatorText.getLayoutBounds().getWidth()
                    ) + 6;

            Line divider = new Line(0, 1, dividerWidth, 1);
            divider.setStrokeWidth(2);

            getChildren().addAll(
                    numeratorText,
                    divider,
                    denominatorText
            );
        }

        public double getBaselineOffset() {
            return offset;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TextFlow flow = new TextFlow(
                new Text("In mathematics, the infinite series "),
                new Fraction(1, 2),
                new Text(" - "),
                new Fraction(1, 4),
                new Text(" + "),
                new Fraction(1, 8),
                new Text(" - "),
                new Fraction(1, 16),
                new Text(" . . . "),
                new Text(" is a simple example of an alternating series that converges absolutely.")
        );
        flow.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        Scene scene = new Scene(flow, 300, 100);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Of course, the above is a pretty simplistic and incomplete solution to a general issue of typesetting math.  If you need sophisticated mathematics typesetting, you could use something like [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org) in a [WebView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html).

Comment: If the nodes should display something looking like a few A4 pages, do you still prefer this approach instead of `Canvas`? Why?

Comment: @gervais.b that is quite different from the original question which was just to display a single fraction.  You could ask a new question, but as is, it would probably get closed as based on opinion.   To give a relevant opinion would need more info on exactly what the output is supposed to look like.

Comment: A4 pages seem to imply that it is optimized for printing, in which case you could use PDF as a format.  JavaFX has a print capability which will allow it to paginate the scene graph.  Canvas will be limited in max size (based on graphic texture), will take a lot of memory to store the textures, and will be a fixed resolution, so won't scale cleanly like vector graphics.  Other formats like PDF, LaTeX, the JavafX Scene Graph or WebView won't have such limitations.

Comment: Consideration may need to be given to authoring requirements, e.g. something like markdown is easier for authoring than html. [Markdown can work with mathjax](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/writing-mathematical-expressions)., but you would need an appropriate implementation to have that work.  There are basic Markdown editors for JavaFX, but probably none that natively support math expression embedded markup.  There will probably be JavaScript libraries that can render markdown math expressions in WebView.

Comment: Indeed, questions asking for opinions have a tendency to be closed. Thanks for sharing your point of view and ideas. However, I was asking from a performance and simplicity point of view. I thought you may have experienced some performances issues with Canvas when there are "many" elements drawn in it. Maybe the `TextFlow` will only render nodes that are visible while the `Canvas` will always draw everything ?

Comment: *you may have experienced some performances issues with Canvas when there are "many" elements drawn in it* -> Yes but **many** in such a case is **a lot**, > 100,000 drawing operations.  In the end it is similar to the scene graph, if the scene graph had > 100,000 nodes it won't perform.  Only, difference with Canvas is that once it is rendered once, the draw command buffer is flushed, so subsequent redraws will be quicker.  However, the scene graph has knowledge for dirty regions and visible nodes, so can cull and optimize based on that.  So you need to prototype your use-case to be sure.

Comment: If you have < 10,000 scene graph nodes or canvas draw commands, performance will likely be fine enough that you don't need to worry about it much (at least for the rendering part rather than your other app logic).

Comment: *Maybe the TextFlow will only render nodes that are visible while the Canvas will always draw everything ?* -> yes, I think JavaFX has some built-in optimizations of the scene graph which will apply to nodes, but not to a very large canvas.  Also, Canvas is limited in the number of pixels it can use (it is a function of the texture size limit of the graphics hardware in use, usually something like 4,096x4096 or 8,192x8,192), so can't create really really big canvases that are large than that, you need to tile, like a [tile engine](https://www.mapeditor.org).

Comment: Also with vectors in a scene graph you get smooth scaling by applying transforms, which you won't get by scaling a canvas (it will go blocky unless you recalculate and redraw all of the primitives for the scaled size).  Plus if you add and remove stuff you have to worry about erasure and implement a painters algorithm, which is already done in the scene graph, so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Anyway, you could always try asking a question and maybe you might get further insight or opinions, worst that can happen is that it will get closed (likely ;-).

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of your code seems to be that the canvases don't have a size. But the whole code seems to be a strange mixture of concepts for me.
Why do you use three separate canvases? Why do you combine them with a VBox? Would you do all that too if you were just writing on a piece of paper?

Comment: Actually I am not familiar with this canvas and JavaFX..
I use each canvas for different type of text i.e canvas for 5 canvas for the seperating line and canvas for the 7
the VBox i use to combine them all to be in a vertical order.
Is there a way to draw on the same canvas 3 different strings?(and applying diffrent fonts and so on for each text?)
Do you have any suggestions about how to implements this rational number view in JavaFX ? (I am willing to read and learn but can you please guide me to which tool I should read about)

Comment: Of course you can draw several things on one canvas. Just have a look at the numerous tutorials and examples on the web. You might start with this one: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/canvas/jfxpub-canvas.htm

Comment: Hey mipa, first thanks alot for your answer!
secondly, I looked for days I even saw the example you gave here but not single example I found that used different fonts for each shape/text.. any guildness/ideas?

Comment: Try this: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#setFont%28javafx.scene.text.Font%29